# Java GUI, why isn't mine showing up?

Tags: java, swing

```
//leaving out import statements


public class MVCView extends JFrame{

private JButton add = new JButton("Click me");
private JTextArea center = new JTextArea(200,300);
private JTextField bottom = new JTextField(200);

public MVCView() {

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(add, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(center, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(bottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    pack();
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);

    }

}


public class MVCTester {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MVCView view = new MVCView();
    }
}
```

I'm just trying to get this to show up on my screen. I create a class with main to create the object which is in a different class. When I click run nothing pops up. I've been following a few tutorials and my code doesn't look much different. Already tried putting everything in a JPanel first which didn't work... I don't know what I'm leaving out or doing wrong.

Comment: That should run. Your JTextArea will be super huge, but otherwise the code  should run, and the GUI should display.

Comment: wtf I'm so confused. I'm running other codes I find online and they work. My code runs but nothing shows up.  EDIT: I just moved everything into a new project folder in eclipse and it's working. I guess my code was doing things with classes in other packages some how... =/

Comment: I'm sorry, didn't clearify that. These were in 2 different files.

Comment: Your main error in that code is that your JTextArea is too big. The int parameters are rows and columns, not pixels.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels *"Your main error in that code is that your JTextArea is too big."* Yes, try instead.. `..new JTextArea(10,15);
.. new JTextField(10);`  and note that Swing GUIs should be created on the EDT.  Also agree with Nathan that you should try running it from the command line to ensure the correct class (the one with main) is being run.

Comment: Got it working now, thanks guys :)

Answer (score 0):

I just modified code you posted and thing works.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;
public class MVCView extends JFrame{

private JButton add = new JButton("Click me");
private JTextArea center = new JTextArea(200,300);
private JTextField bottom = new JTextField(200);

public MVCView() {

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(add, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(center, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(bottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    pack();
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);

    }





public static void main(String[] args) {
    MVCView view = new MVCView();
    }
}
```